# Argument-position aware custom tab completers for a funcion in Ipython

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have successfully added custom tab completer for a function to be used in my ipython notebook by following the advice at: http://wiki.ipython.org/index.php?title=Cookbook/Custom_completers.

However, I want the custom completer to be aware of the position of the current argument where tab is being pressed. If it is the first argument to the function at hand, complete with values relevant to the first argument, if it is second, fill with valid values for second arg and so on.

Any way to achieve this kind of positional tab-completers?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have put a merged list of all possible values of all arguments into the function's tab completer. Since the values of different args are mutually exclusive, my purpose is served even though a more elegant solution would be better.